# trigger a celery job via django singnals

Tags: python, django, celery

I would like to use Django signals to trigger a celery task like so:

```
def delete_content(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    task_id = uuid()
    task = delete_libera_contents.apply_async(kwargs={"instance": instance}, task_id=task_id)
    task.wait(timeout=300, interval=2)
```

But I'm always running into  `kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type MusicTracks is not JSON serializable`

Now I'm not sure how to tread MusicTracks instance as it's a model class instance. How can I properly pass such instances to my task?

At my tasks.py I have the following:

```
@app.task(name="Delete Libera Contents", queue='high_priority_tasks')
def delete_libera_contents(instance, **kwargs):

    libera_backend = instance.file.libera_backend
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Never send `instance` in celery task, you only should send `variables` for example `instanse primary key` and then inside of the celery task via this `pk` find this `instance` and then do your logic

your code should be like this:

`views.py`

```
def delete_content(sender, **kwargs):
    task_id = uuid()
    task = delete_libera_contents.apply_async(kwargs={"instance_pk": sender.pk}, task_id=task_id)
    task.wait(timeout=300, interval=2)
```

`task.py`

```
@app.task(name="Delete Libera Contents", queue='high_priority_tasks')
def delete_libera_contents(instance_pk, **kwargs):

    instance = Instance.ojbects.get(pk = instance_pk)
    libera_backend = instance.file.libera_backend
    ...
```

you can find this rule in celery documentation (can't find link), one of
reasons  imagine situation:

1. you send your instance to celery tasks (it is delayed for any reason for 5 min)
2. then your project makes logic with this instance, `before` your task finished
3. then celery's task time come and it uses this instance old version, and this instance become corrupted

(this is the reason as I think it is, not from the documentation)

Comment: I had quite a similar Idea but at tasks.py you write instance = Instance.ojbects.get(pk=instance_pk) where I don't know Instance. Instance is a model class and can either be MusicTrack, TvShowsEpisodes or Movies

Comment: your instance is in `sender` variable, if you used `post_save.connect(delete_content, sender= MusicTrack)` this should be `sender` not `instance`, print your variables and take a look on it, `print(sender) and print(instance)` in `delete_libera_contents function`, i've updated my answer

Comment: This can't work, what is instance = Instance.ojbects.get(pk = instance_pk). Explicitly asking what is Instance. This task can trigger against 3 different model classes. where do you know Instance from? Makes no sense to me

Comment: this solution 100% solve problem asked in this question, but doesn't solve problem that you don't know how signals works, one signal send one instance, if you do send 3 instances via 3 signals to one function you need first to find which instance in particular you recieve. If you want help with your multiple singals, how about share code of them? You only shared one, and even not with full code, and my solution works for one model as you asked

Comment: @VO `what is instance = Instance.ojbects.get(pk = instance_pk`
 this is what your signal sends to your function, signal can send only ONE instance to delete_content fucntion. `Makes no sense to me` if it doesn't make sense to you, maybe you are should hire a tutor

Comment: Okay, solved the issue, but differently. From my understanding, we have totally achieved the goal to talk past each other xD. Will post my answer is a second. And thanks for your help besides

Answer (score 1):

First off, sorry for making the question a bit confusing, especially for the people that have already written an answer.
In my case, the delete_content signal can be trigger from three different models, so it actually looks like this:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MusicTracks)
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Movies)
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=TvShowEpisodes)
def delete_content(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    delete_libera_contents.delay(instance_pk=instance.pk)
```

So every time one of these models triggers a delete action, this signal will also trigger a celery task to actually delete the stuff in the background (all stored on S3).

As I cannot and should not pass instances around directly as pointed out by @oruchkin, I pass the instance.pk to the celery task which I then have to find in the celery task as I don't know in the celery task what model has triggered the delete action:

```
@app.task(name="Delete Libera Contents", queue='high_priority_tasks')
def delete_libera_contents(instance_pk, **kwargs):

    if Movies.objects.filter(pk=instance_pk).exists():
        instance = Movies.objects.get(pk=instance_pk)
    elif MusicTracks.objects.filter(pk=instance_pk).exists():
        instance = MusicTracks.objects.get(pk=instance_pk)
    elif TvShowEpisodes.objects.filter(pk=instance_pk).exists():
        instance = TvShowEpisodes.objects.get(pk=instance_pk)
    else:
        raise logger.exception("Task: 'Delete Libera Contents', reports: No instance found (code: JFN4LK) - Warning")

    libera_backend = instance.file.libera_backend
```

You might ask why do you not simply pass the sender from the signal to the celery task. I also tried this and again, as already pointed out, I cannot pass instances and I fail with:

```
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type ModelBase is not JSON serializable
```

So it really seems I have to hard obtain the instance using the if-elif-else clauses at the celery task.

Comment: this works, but it looks inefficient, in the worst case you will make 3 sql requests, you can find which . You can find which model has been send with this `print(type(kwargs['instance']))` and `print((str(type(kwargs['instance'])).split("."))[2].split("'")[0])`  It might be better in this case to create 3 different functions here to reduce sql requests. also it is a good manner to upvote answers which was helpful.